Load data from an existing table into a temporal table
I would like to update the temporal with the whole daily updated staging table.
The staging table does not have auto-increment id and system time which the temporal table has, I have tried to use this command:
insert into TemporalTable 
select * from StagingTable

But the error says that column number does not match. So I wonder if I should add ID and ValidFrom ValidTo column to the staging table before I insert to the temporal table. I thought these three columns could auto-generate because when inserting single record into temporal table, it does auto-generate.

INSERTing/UPDATEing a temporal table is no different to doing so to a non-temporal table. That the data engine does additional work to store a history of the data doesn't change what your INSERT/UPDATE looks like. The table are, in fact, design so that you don't need different syntax to INSERT/UPDATE them.

Hi friend, thanks for your answer! So if I just do regular insert or update, do I need to include the id and timestamp in the command or I can just insert the data and the temporal table will automatically add them?

You shouldn't need a timestamp (rowversion) for a temporal table, as you'll be able to see the date the row was last updated from your Valid From column. As for the id, if you want to UPDATE a specific ID then yes, you'll need to include that in your WHERE, otherwise how would SQL server know what row you're updating?

Presumably, however, you have tried INSERTing/UPDATEing your table and its failed (otherwise you wouldn't be here), so what was that attempt? What was the error you received or why didn't the statement(s) work as you expect?

I tried and the error says the column doesn't match, so I was wondering if I should add id, valid from, valid to in the staging table and then insert into temporal table, cuz I thought the temporal table should be able to generate these three columns itself.

[Edit] your question demonstrate what the real problem is. Don't forget to include an [mre].

I think the confusion comes from "update the temp with records from the staging table". I suspect you are actually just dumping new records from staging into temp. This most easily done via "Insert Into". You can specify which columns are inserted from the staging tale. The other temp columns should get their default or auto-incremented values.

When INSERTing always specifying the columns you are INSERTing into. Also, don't use SELECT * either, be explicit: INSERT INTO <Schema Name>.<Table Name> (<Column List>) SELECT <Column List> FROM <Schema Name>.<Table Name>;.

INSERT INTO <target_table> SELECT  FROM <source_table>
From the docs.
You could add an identity column and datetime column to the stanging table - if that wouldn't hurt the original update, you can then fix the current datetime into the latter column and the former will be auto-populated.
